# Sharepoint provided hosted app client context on Web Api project

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, provider-hosted-app

I have a visual studio solution with the folowing projects:

```
  -Provided hosted app 
  -Asp.net MVC 
  -Asp.net Web api
```

Is it possible to use CSOM within Web api project? So I can consume the web api form the MVC project. I've done some research and I can not find any example. I just found a way to make CSOM work on an API within MVC project, but not in a different project. Both projects are located on Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that SharePoint Helper class are designed to work with MVC Controller makes a case for modification in these helper files to adapt to WebApi ApiController.

There is this blog [Getting SharePoint 2013 apps and WebAPI to work](http://blog.baslijten.com/getting-sharepoint-2013-apps-and-webapi-to-work/) by Bas Lijten which should lead you to the solution.